# Customizing Twitter Bootstrap Grid Does not Work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to make a 24 column grid. I calculated this:

Site Width: 997px

Number of Columns: 24

Column Width: 31px

Gutter Width: 11px

Fluid Column Width: 3.1093279839519%

Fluid Gutter Width: 1.1033099297894%

Which should work, but when I input it into the customize form (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html) and download span8 is 778px when it should be 248px the weird thing is that it still goes up to span24, so it IS changing... it's just getting it wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me

```
.span8 {
  width: 325px;
}

.span24 {
  width: 997px;
}
```

Just check that you really are changing the right fields, empty your browser cache, check that you are opening the right files and use [this url](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html). Be careful not to be misguided by the placeholders.

If it's still not working, you can download the less files, change the few variables in `variables.less` and compile it yourself (get help [here](http://lesscss.org) or with [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vXXFdvnk)).

Comment: Can you send me a link of it working? I know that it has that span in the css file, but at other sizes (such as like 1175px it breaks again, also tablet size breaks.

Comment: @PixMach Here is the POST data submitted by the form http://pastebin.com/cafzPrnM and the archive http://www.mirari.fr/EAYQ And it breaks because responsive layout is NOT modified by the variables. You have to do it manually in the responsive less files, and compile.