# Twitter Bootstrap 24 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customizing Twitter Bootstrap Grid Does not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854808/customizing-twitter-bootstrap-grid-does-not-work)

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap grid with 24 columns and fluid grid system.

I customized my css here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html by setting the 3 grid variables:

```
@gridColumns:24
@gridColumnWidth:30px
@gridGutterWidth:10px
```

and the fluid grid system too:

```
@fluidGridColumnWidth:3.2%
@fluidGridGutterWidth:1.06%
```

By this way, I still have a 12 columns grid.

I tried to edit it manually in the less files (variables.less) and compiled less files to get my bootstrap.css but I can't get 24 columns.

what is the trick?

Comment: When I go to the customization page and set 24 columns, 30px column width and 10px gutter width, and then download, I get a CSS file with the appropriate classes for a 24 column layout: `.span13-24`, .offset13-24`, etc. Not sure what problem you're having.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/11854808/1478467